# Getting errors when trying to 'next build && next export'

Tags: webpack, next.js, webpack-5

I'm trying to build and export my Next.js app. However, the build is failing, producing the following error below, which is repeated for every page.

```
[  ==] info  - Generating static pages (0/30)
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: 
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Cannot find module for page: /
    at pageNotFoundError
```

This is the final error output:

```
> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /
    /about-meadowvalefoods
    /careers
    /case-studies
    /case-studies/[id]
    /contact-us
    /export
    /find-a-supplier
    /industry-news
    /industry-news/[id]
    /my-account/dashboard
    /our-companies
    /our-products
    /our-products/1
    /our-products/10
    /our-products/11
    /our-products/12
    /our-products/13
    /our-products/14
    /our-products/15
    /our-products/2
    /our-products/3
    /our-products/4
    /our-products/5
    /our-products/6
    /our-products/7
    /our-products/8
    /our-products/9
    /point-of-sale
    /point-of-sale/images
```

info  - Using webpack 5 and
"next": "11.0.1",

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: the error should come from your index.js page

Comment: All pages are working in dev mode

Comment: the error occurs when next tries to optimize your page

Comment: Could you please show us the code for the index page?

Comment: @juliomalves Unfortunately not, the repo is private.

Comment: Without seeing the actual code it's hard to tell what the issue is.

Comment: I got this same error yesterday (multiple times), turns out if you try to `next build` at a same time  dev server (`next dev`) running you will get these types of errors.
So never run dev server when you are building, also you may have to delete `.next/` folder before building.